# Setup Kubernetes Pods via API Call using Go and Operator SDK

Tags: go, kubernetes, operator-sdk, kubebuilder

I am trying to create a controller that can create and delete Pods via API calls using `operator-sdk` with `Go`. The controller should be able to accept a `POST` call with information such as `{imageTag:"", namespace:""}` to setup a Pod that can return a `podId`, and also be able to delete a Pod via API call using `podId`.

I have reviewed some tutorials, but I am unclear on how the Go operator can intercept API calls. Is this possible? Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found that Kubernetes Client and Kubernetes Operator are two different concepts.
Ended up creating a Kubernetes Go Client using which I was able achieve my goal.

You can refer the library here.
https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go